# HHVM fallback to PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I am running a PHP application on nginx with HHVM as main and PHP-FPM as backup

This is my config of nginx regarding the php processing

```
  location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 500 501 502 503 = @fallback;

    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_keep_conn on;

    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME $host;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  location @fallback {

    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME $host;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

  }
```

To test the config,I stopped the hhvm service.Normally that would pass the request to PHP-FPM and should return 200 but I am getting 502 error as follows :

```
12296#0: *17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.34.235, server: stylep3.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host:localhost
```

Am I doing anything wrong here

Answer (score 5):

This is doable in a much simpler way.

First define an upstream with hhvm and php-fpm as a backup.

```
upstream fastcgi_server {
  server unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
  server unix:/var/run/php-fpm-mysite.sock backup;
}
```

Then just use `fastcgi_server` as if were the only backend, nginx deals with the failover work, not you.

```
fastcgi_pass fastcgi_server;
```

Module upstream docs are very enlightening.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Summarizing, your example would look like this:

```
upstream php_backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
  server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock backup;
}


server {
#
# other conf...
#

 location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_keep_conn on;

    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME $host;
    fastcgi_pass    php_backend;
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this one too.I know what I wrote is redundant but since this config did not work,I wrote the conf in that way but even that throws the error.

Comment: I found it,

Apparently,according to official instructions I included hhvm.conf in the nginx vhost that seems to override php-fpm and trying to connect to it!

Removing it solved the problem

Comment: @5ud0 I have production servers running with this config, it works flawlessly

Comment: yeah,it worked for me too,but hhvm seems to be alot slow compared to php-fpm,I know that it has JIT warmup initially.

Comment: @5ud0 Yes, warmup is important for hhvm, I have a script running `siege -b -f urls.txt -v`, after 30 seconds the speed gets considerably better.

Comment: I am doing the same :D . But it seems less effective in my case!

Well,the company made me shift to apache *sigh*

Comment: @5ud0 Have you tried all these hhvm tips? https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Performance-Tuning